# ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, wagtail

I have an error written in the header. I have two Page models which use `InlinePanel`s:

```
class TournamentPage(Page):
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    ends_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('starts_at'),
        FieldPanel('ends_at'),
        InlinePanel(
            'groupstage_tournament_relationship', label="Goups",
            panels=None, min_num=1),
        InlinePanel(
            'final_phase_relationship', label="Finals",
            panels=None, min_num=1),
    ]

    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ScreencastPage(Page):

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel(
            'groupstage_screencast_relationship', label="Playing First",
            panels=None, max_num=1),
        InlinePanel(
            'final_phase_relationship', label="Playing Next",
            panels=None, max_num=1),
    ]

    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']
    subpage_types = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And if i click add new Tournament Page or Screencast Page i got this error:

`Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Here is the Traceback of Screencast Page: http://dpaste.com/0RKCZJH

And Tournament Page: http://dpaste.com/1SVS1BA

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure that this could be the reason, but I will say, when I did the migration, I needed to enter '' as a default value for some fields. Perhaps the python prescribed them where it is not necessary. I did it using console.

Here is my GroupstageTournamentModel and FinalphaseTournamentModel. Relationship Models included too.

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default="", verbose_name="Match №:")
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(default="",)
    # Team 1
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Erste Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_1_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_1_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_1_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_1_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')
    # Team 2
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Zweite Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_2_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_2_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_2_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_2_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_2_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_2_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('number', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('starts_at', classname="col6"),
        # Team 1
        FieldPanel('team_1', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_points', classname="col3"),
        # Team 2
        FieldPanel('team_2', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_points', classname="col3"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} vs {} {} - {}'.format(self.team_1, self.team_2, self.starts_at, self.number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gruppenphase Spiel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gruppenphase'

class GroupstageTournamentRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('TournamentPage',
        null=True, blank=True, default="",
        related_name='groupstage_tournament_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        null=True, blank=True, default="",
        related_name='match_tournament_relationship', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]
class MatchesScreencastRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('ScreencastPage',
        null=True, blank=True, default="",
        related_name='groupstage_screencast_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        null=True, blank=True, default="",
        related_name='match_screen_relationship')
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]

class FinalphaseTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        help_text="Add the unique number of this Match.")
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField()
    # Team 1
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Erste Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_1_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_1_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_1_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_1_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')
    # Team 2
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamRooster,
        null=True, default="", verbose_name='Zweite Team',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    team_2_dress = ColorField(default='#ff0000', blank=True, verbose_name='Dress')
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_2_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_2_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_2_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_2_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_2_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default="0", verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('number', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('starts_at', classname="col6"),
        # Team 1
        FieldPanel('team_1', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_1_total_points', classname="col3"),
        # Team 2
        FieldPanel('team_2', classname="col9"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_dress', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_score', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_first_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_second_halftime_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_shootout_point', classname="col3"),
        FieldPanel('team_2_total_points', classname="col3"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} vs {} {} - {}'.format(self.team_1, self.team_2, self.starts_at, self.number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Finalphase Spiel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Finalphase'

class FinalphaseTournamentRelationship(Orderable, FinalphaseTournamentModel):
    page = ParentalKey('TournamentPage', related_name='final_phase_relationship')
class FinalphaseScreencastRelationship(Orderable, FinalphaseTournamentModel):
    page = ParentalKey('ScreencastPage', related_name='final_phase_relationship')
```

And I deleted `title` fields as @loïc-teixeira suggest.

**UPDATE**

I added also traceback from console

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/pages/add/tournament/screencastpage/3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'MatchesScreencastRelationship' object has no attribute '_match_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 43, in _cache_controlled
    response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\urls\__init__.py", line 96, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\decorators.py", line 31, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\views\pages.py", line 289, in create
    'has_unsaved_changes': has_unsaved_changes,
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 204, in render_form_content
    return mark_safe(self.render_as_object() + self.render_missing_fields())
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 172, in render_as_object
    return self.render()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 273, in render
    'self': self
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 172, in render_as_object
    return self.render()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 273, in render
    'self': self
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 172, in render_as_object
    return self.render()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 726, in render
    'can_order': self.formset.can_order,
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\templatetags\wagtailadmin_tags.py", line 225, in render
    out = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 216, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 204, in render_form_content
    return mark_safe(self.render_as_object() + self.render_missing_fields())
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 172, in render_as_object
```

*Can not add all but here is the end*

```
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1270, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1210, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1104, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 74, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "D:\GitHub\treichle_cup\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[10/Feb/2018 23:57:26] "GET /admin/pages/add/tournament/screencastpage/3/?next=/admin/tournament/screencastpage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 605452
```

Comment: The stacktrace mention the related descriptor/field a couple time which might indicate that the error in on the models you're trying to inline. Could you add the definition of the group stage and final phase for both the screencast and the tournament page?

Comment: As a side note, in your `content_panels`, since you use `Page.content_panels` and defines a `FieldPanel` for `title` as well, you'll have a duplicated field in the admin.

Comment: I created a completely new project and even in it I get the same error. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong, like everything is the same as in the [backerydemo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/0565aaeeba0aac1355683f9e536e1e398775c80c/bakerydemo/blog/models.py#L23) and in documentation [documentaions](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/panels.html?highlight=inlinepanel#inline-panels-and-model-clusters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part

```
number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    default="", verbose_name="Match №:")
```

If you have `PositiveSmallIntegerField` the default should be int, not string (for example `1`, instead of `""`).

Comment: I checked with 1 and with "1", in both cases received the same error.

Comment: @khashashin You've actually needed to remove EVERY `default=""` or `default="0"`. You've received same error, but from another line.

Comment: No, Im didn't remove another `default=" "` definitions

Comment: Actually I didn't remove `default=""` from `number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    default="", verbose_name="Match №:")` too, and it still works

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside my relationship models, I did not need to add a value `default=""` inside this models. So just deleted `default=""` from relationship models and its works (actually it has yet another problem but that's another question.)

```
class GroupstageTournamentRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('TournamentPage',
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='groupstage_tournament_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='match_tournament_relationship', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]
class MatchesScreencastRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey('ScreencastPage',
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='groupstage_screencast_relationship')
    match = models.ForeignKey('GroupstageTournamentModel',
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='match_screen_relationship')
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('match')
    ]
```